# What is the correct order np.dot(inputs, weights) or np.dot(weights, inputs)?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network

```
import numpy as np

inputs = [1, 2, 3, 4]
weights = [[0.3, 0.5, 0.2, -0.5],
           [1.0, 0.2, -1, 0.5],
           [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 2.5],
           [2.0, 5.0, -1.0, 2.0],
           [-1.5, 2.7, 3.3, -0.8],
           [0.65, 0.24, 5.0, 2.3],
           [2.0, 1.2, 0.5, -2]]
biases = [1, 2, 2.5, 3, 0.54, 0.65, 2.2]

layer_outputs = np.dot(inputs, weights) + biases
print(layer_outputs)
```

I am following the book Neural Networks from Scratch by Harrison Kinsley in which while giving the explanation for the order of np.dot() he writes:

> To explain the order of parameters we are passing into np.dot(), we
> should think of it as whatever comes first will decide the output
> shape.
>
> In our case, we are passing a list of neuron weights first and then
> the inputs, as our goal is to get a list of neuron outputs.
>
> As we mentioned, a dot product of a matrix and a vector results in a
> list of dot products.
>
> The np.dot() method treats the matrix as a list of vectors and
> performs a dot product of each of those vectors with the other vector.
>
> In this example, we used that property to pass a matrix, which was a
> list of neuron weight vectors and a vector of inputs and get a list of
> dot products — neuron outputs.

What does he mean by "*whatever comes first will decide the output shape*"?
I am interpreting it as:

My inputs is a list having 4 elements and the weights is a list of lists; having 7 lists of 4 numbers, each of these 7 corresponding to the weights for a particular neuron.

So according to the matrix multiplication rule the only way to multiply is to do inputs(1,4)*weights(7,4) for which I will have to take the transpose of the weight matrix but we are just passing the weights as it is to np.dot(). Does np.dot() do the transpose of second argument by itself?

Comment: The documentation is very clear about what the function computes: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html

Answer (score 0):

`inputs` as a array has (4,) shape.  `weights` will be (7,4). `biases` (7,)

(7,4) dotted with (4,) will produce a (7,) shape, which matches `biases`.

(4,) with (7,4) will raise an error.

`dot(A,B)` for 2d arrays matches the last dim of A with the 2nd to last of `B`.  If `B` is 1d, the only dimension qualifies as `2nd to the last`.  For 1d `A`, the one dimension is clearly the last.

Comment: Thank you for making it clear. Is it always "2nd to last dimension"(other than 1D) or can I interchange with the "1st dim of B"? What if I have arrays of more than 2 dim?

Comment: Remember how to do matrix product by hand?  Across rows, down columns?  For more dimensions compare `np.dot` and `np.matmul` docs.  For more options study `np.einsum`.